# Images "jumps" into the grid? how to stup the jump effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

**This is my script;**

```
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/mviqmwg/XyYn59y3a/jquery.photoset-grid.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {                
    $('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid({
        gutter: '0px',
});
});
</script>
<!-- /Photoset-grid script -->
```

**This makes the images "jump into grid effect"**

I want everything to show up normaly.

Is there a hide effect with css and then show it when everything is loaded?

Thank you for anny advice!

Comment: Did my answer serve you well?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for Photosetgrid:

https://github.com/stylehatch/photoset-grid/

You can see that they use a simple style tag: style="visibility: hidden;"

If you prefer to use jquery it would be:
$(".photoset-grid").hide();

To make it visible it would be this way:

```
  $('.photoset-grid-basic').photosetGrid({
        onComplete: function(){
          $('.photoset-grid-basic').attr('style', '');
//or $('.photoset-grid-basic').show();
        }
      });
```

You can see more info about its usage here:

http://stylehatch.github.io/photoset-grid/#demo-basic-usage

Comment: Thank you! Where to I put this: 'visiblity': 'visible' to make it show when it is loaded??